# 'DirectoryIterator' Class not found

Tags: php, symfony

I'm new to simfony2, so sorry for the newbie question.

When I try to use some classes, such as `DirectoryIterator` or `DOMDocument` I receive the following exception:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'My\TestBundle\Command\DirectoryIterator' not found in /var/www/simfony2/src/My/TestBundle/Command/TestCommand.php on line 214
```

If try to run the same code outside the simfony2 environment it code runs fine, `phpinfo()` shows  `PHP Version => 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.4` and the include path is the default plus added ZF2.

Again, I know this is probably some configuration issue as it searches the class in my bundle rather than using the build-in php class but I can't figure out how to solve this.

Edit:
This is copy of the code I'm trying to execute:

```
protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) {
 $classes=get_declared_classes();
 print_r($classes);      
 $d= new DirectoryIterator("/");
}
```

When I run the command I can see the class

```
...
[73] => DirectoryIterator
...
```

But I can't use it

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is [namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rules.php) related!

Has nothing to do with symfony itself.
you should ad `\` before a global class inside another namespace

```
$class = new \DirectoryIterator;
```

I suggest you read the php manual first before continuing with symfony!

Comment: Thank you. I've been using php for a while, but never used namespaces before, plus the get_declared_classes() shes it without the leading slash. :)

Comment: @SimSimY i admit, the way php integrated namespaces is confusing at first and doesn't make much sense. ;)